# Implementing a BFS-search method for a graph

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm implementing my own graph class. My undirected graph is represented by a map which maps every node to a list storing the edges it has.

```
    private Map<T, List<Edge<T>>> graphRep = new HashMap<>();

    private static class Edge<T> {
        int cost;
        T node;
        public Edge(T n, int w) {
            node = n;
            cost = w;
        }
```

I have already created a recursive depth-first traversal method for my graph which utilizes a map to store the path between the start node to the search node. It does by mapping every node the next node on the path between the start node to end node.

```
    @Override
    public List<T> depthFirstSearch(T start, T end) {
        Set<T> visited = new HashSet<T>();
        Map<T,T> path = new HashMap<>();
        recursiveDFS(start, end, visited,path);
        List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
        T current = end;
        myList.add(current);
        while (current != start) {
            myList.add(path.get(current));
            current = path.get(current);
        }
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(myList);
        Collections.reverse(myList);
        return myList;
    }

    private void recursiveDFS (T node, T end, Set<T> visited, Map<T, T> path) {
        // uppdatera path och visited
        visited.add(node);
        for (Edge<T> e : graphRep.get(node)) {
            if (e.node == end) {
                path.put(e.node, node);
                return;
            }
            if (!visited.contains(e.node)){
                path.put(e.node, node);
                recursiveDFS(e.node, end, visited, path);
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe I can utilize essentially the same code for the breadth-first search as with the depth-first search, only that the instead of traversing the nodes by depth I traverse them by breadth, and that's where I'm stuck. I'm completely lost on how to do that.

```
    @Override
    public List<T> breadthFirstSearch(T start, T end) {

        Set<T> visited = new HashSet<T>();
        Map<T,T> path = new HashMap<>();
        recursiveBFS(start, end, visited,path);
        List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
        T current = end;
        myList.add(current);
        while (current != start) {
            myList.add(path.get(current));
            current = path.get(current);
        }
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(myList);
        Collections.reverse(myList);
        return myList;
    }

    public void recursiveBFS (T node, T end, Set<T> visited, Map<T, T> path) {

        visited.add(node);
        for (Edge<T> e : graphRep.get(node)) {
            if (e.node == end) {
                path.put(e.node, node);
                return;
            }
            if (!visited.contains(node)) {
              //Here's where I'm stuck. I have no idea how to traverse the graph by breadth
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I complete my breadth-first traversal method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BFS** requires a container that will allow to retrieve nodes in the order they were visited. It can't be achieved with a `Map`. You need a `Queue` for that purpose ([take a look carefully at the description of this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).

***Note** that although BFS could be implemented recursively, the iterative approach is way better for this task.*

Firstly, you need to create a **queue** and add a *starting node* into it. Then the **queue** will be passed as an argument to the `recursiveBFS()`.

At each call of the `recursiveBFS()` a *node* at the beginning of the **queue** will be removed. If the queue is empty that will mean that the *start-node* and *end-node* are not connected.

That is how recursive implementation might look like:

```
public List<T> breadthFirstSearch(T start, T end) {
    Map<T, T> paths = new HashMap<>();
    Queue<T> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    queue.add(start);
    recursiveBFS(end, new HashSet<>(), queue, paths);

    return getPath(start, end, paths);
}

public void recursiveBFS(T end, Set<T> visited, Queue<T> queue,  Map<T, T> paths) {
    if (queue.isEmpty()) { // start-node and end-node are not connected
        return;
    }

    T parentNode = queue.remove();
    visited.add(parentNode);
    for (Edge<T> edge : graphRep.get(parentNode)) { // avoid one-letter variables like "e" instead of edge
        if (visited.contains(parentNode)) {
            continue;
        }
        paths.put(edge.node, parentNode);
        // end node was found
        if (edge.node.equals(end)) { // don't compare object with "=="
            return;
        }
        recursiveBFS(end, visited, queue, paths); // this line was missing
    }
}
```

In order to make this solution adhere to the [**Single responsibility principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) I extracted the logic for restoring the path from the *start-node* to *end-node* from the `breadthFirstSearch()`  into the separate method.

```
public List<T> getPath(T start, T end,  Map<T, T> paths) {
    List<T> path = new ArrayList<T>();
    T current = end;
    path.add(current);
    while (current != start && current != null) { // if there's no path from start to end current eventually will become null
        path.add(paths.get(current));
        current = paths.get(current);
    }
    System.out.println(path);
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return current != null ? path : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

**Recommendations:**

- The most important I want to point out is the overall design of your *graph*. While traversing the graph you heavily rely on the `Map<T, List<Edge<T>>> graphRep`, **edges** are helpless without it. You might consider refining your graph so that its elements will be more self-contained. Firstly, in my opinion, the *edge* of a graph has to have **two** references because by definition it is meant to represent a connection *between two vertices* of the *graph*. And if you add a `Vertex` class to your *graph* then will contain reference a *collection of edges* then you can implement graph traversal algorithms using only *edges* and *vertexes* without a need to fall back on `graphRep`.
- don't compare object with `==`, use `equals()` method instead.
- avoid one-letter variables like `e`.
- don't name like `myList`, but try to come up with the name that explains the purpose of this variable (like `path`).

---

**Update**

Below is an iterative implementation of **BFS**:

```
public List<T> breadthFirstSearch(T start, T end) {
    Map<T, T> paths = new HashMap<>();
    Set<T> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Queue<T> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    queue.add(start);
    visited.add(start);
    boolean isFound = false;
    while (!isFound && !queue.isEmpty()) {
        T parentNode = queue.remove();
        for (Edge<T> edge : graphRep.get(parentNode)) {
            if (!visited.add(edge.node)) {
                continue;
            }
            paths.put(edge.node, parentNode);
            // end node was found
            if (edge.node.equals(end)) {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return getPath(start, end, paths);
}
```

An iterative solution would be cleaner if you take into account recommendation above. And since for **BFS** as well as for **DFS** we don't need any information specific to **edges** (because **vertex** (node) can store data about *adjusent vertexes*) these algorithms could be implemented using **vertecies** only.